# Oracle Advanced Queueing: Change Queue Properties at Runtime

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-aq

We use queues in our application, we need to give the user the ability to change queues properties `MAX_RETRIES` and `RETRY_DELAY` from the application.

Is it possible to change those properties when queues are started and running?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can change the max_retries parameter using the DBMS_AQADM.ALTER_QUEUE procedure. Have you tried this while the queue is open for dequeue to see what happens?

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried what you suggested. and the alter works fine but i didn't find a way to check that the queue is started. I had already use dbms_aqadm.start_queue(). I found that in user_queue_schedules Table there's a field current_start_time, but when i query this table i got nothing maybe no queue is started !!!

Comment: To see if the queue is enabled for enqueue and dequeue, have a look in user_queues. I think user_queue_schedules is more for propagation of messages to other queues than straight forward enqueue and dequeue.

Comment: Thanks Stephen your comments were so helpful.